# 14sums - the diamond standard

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, calculation-puzzle

My [initial question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/76325/21sums-more-constraints) had lots of answers, and [my second](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/76325/21sums-more-constraints) had too many constraints. So, I have removed some constraints and added another. Same rules as before, but we are now using $[0,6]\cap\mathbb{Z}$. Also, the four corners should sum to $15$, the number at top-left.

> ```
> 15             5       
>    ---    ---    ---    ---
>        15      7     11     
>    ---    ---    ---    ---
> 11     17      8     10     8
>    ---    ---    ---    ---
>        13     13     15     
>    ---    ---    ---    ---
>                7
> ```

**Can you solve this diamond grid?**

Answer (score 4):

In the spaces, from top to bottom:

> 6 3 2 5 
>  5 1 1 3 
>  6 5 1 5 
>  1 1 6 3

Comment: correct, but not the one I've got!